# LEFT JOIN MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get some statitics out for my adminpanel.
I have two tables named users and cms_prosjekt. I want to count how many projects
that have the same attribute as users.

Each user have a motto that is connected to a project.
For example: Motto is spirit and the project code is spirit. It won't return anything. I have two users with the same motto as code in a project.

```
 <?php 

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT
      users.id,

      COUNT(users.motto) AS count
    FROM
      users
      LEFT JOIN cms_prosjekt ON
        users.motto=cms_prosjekt.code
    GROUP BY
      users.motto");
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  echo "$num_rows";

  ?>
```

Comment: if the query succeeded, you'd get a number. Since you get NOTHING, your query failed, returned boolean false, and since you have absolutely NO error handling and simply assumed that nothing could ever get wrong, you get that boolean false as a string, which is a zero-length/invisible string.

Comment: As I wrote, I have two users that have the same motto as an project. So it should return two?

Comment: Don't use the deprecated mysql_ interface functions for new development. Use mysqli or PDO. This code is putting it's figurative pinky finger to the corner of it's figurative mouth, saying Dr.Evil style "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?"   If the query encounters an error, MySQL will return an error message. This code appears to be entirely ignoring the idea that MySQL might return an error.

Comment: If there is at least one row in the users table, and if the query execution is successful, then the query would return at least one row, whether the `motto` of a `user` matched the `code` of a projekt or not. The number of rows returned by this query (again assuming that it executes successfully) would be the number of distinct values of `motto` in the `users` table. Was there a *question*? Or were you just sharing a status report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be  count(*) and group by user.motto

```
 "SELECT
    user.motto
  , COUNT( * ) AS count
 FROM  users
 LEFT JOIN cms_prosjekt ON  users.motto=cms_prosjekt.code
 GROUP BY  users.motto"
```

Answer (score 0):

The group by should be users.id not users.motto :

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT users.id, COUNT(users.motto) AS count FROM users LEFT JOIN cms_prosjekt ON users.motto=cms_prosjekt.code GROUP BY (users.id)");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
?>
```

Note : i can't see any value  for the left join you don't need any data from  cms_prosjek but i keep it if you will use it later

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but now I want to add a specific user id to the query. Since every administrator have their own home area, I want to list all the users that is connected to a specific administrator. Each administrator is creating projects with users.

I tried this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT users.motto, COUNT( * ) AS count FROM  users 
WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'
LEFT JOIN cms_prosjekt ON  users.motto=cms_prosjekt.code 
GROUP BY  users.motto");
```